# How to exclude the singularities by using FunctionSingularities

Tags: numerical-integration

I want to compute a integration like

```
F = 1/x + 1/(x + 1);
NIntegrate[F, {x, -3, 2}, Method -> "PrincipalValue", Exclusions -> FunctionSingularities[F, x]]
```

However, it occurs a error

```
"Incorrect Exclusions specification x==-1||x==0."
```

But when I put the two singularities by hand

```
NIntegrate[F, {x, -3, 2}, Method -> "PrincipalValue", Exclusions -> {-1,0}]
```

It does the job. Any one know how to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general exclusions syntax is a list of expressions or of conditional expressions, `{sing, condition}`:

```
Join @@ FunctionProperties`Singularities[f, {x}]

(*  {{x == 0, True}, {1 + x == 0, True}}  *)
```

Thus:

```
NIntegrate[f, {x, -3, 2}, Method -> "PrincipalValue", 
 Exclusions -> Join @@ FunctionProperties`Singularities[f, {x}]]

(*  -4.44089*10^-16  *)
```

It produces a list of exclusions that `NIntegrate` accepts for `Log[x]`:

```
FunctionProperties`Singularities[Log@x, {x}]

(*  {{{Im[x] == 0, Re[x] <= 0}}, {}, {}, {}, {{x == 0, True}}}  *)
```

If we don't want to exclude the whole negative real axis, we should use only the point singularities:

```
FunctionProperties`Singularities[Log[x], {x}, {"POINTS"}]
(*  {{}, {}, {}, {}, {{x == 0, True}}}  *)

NIntegrate[Log[x], {x, -1, 1}, Exclusions -> Join @@
  FunctionProperties`Singularities[Log[x], {x}, {"POINTS"}]]
(*  -2. + 3.14159 I  *)

NIntegrate[Log[x], {x, -1, 1}, Exclusions -> Join @@
  FunctionProperties`Singularities[Log[x], {x}]]
(*  -1.  <-- equals the integral over {x, 0, 1} *)
```

---

`` FunctionProperties`Singularities `` returns a list of five lists of function singularities, similar to `FunctionSingularities` except singularities in the complex plane are returned, each singularity is joined to a condition, and they are separated into five categories, which seem to be as the examples below show:

```
(* Branch cuts,..., branch points *)
FunctionProperties`Singularities[Log[x], {x}]
(*  {{{Im[x] == 0, Re[x] <= 0}}, {}, {}, {}, {{x == 0, True}}}  *)

(* (Piecewise) discontinuities *)
FunctionProperties`Singularities[Sign[x + 1], {x}]
(*  {{}, {{1 + x == 0, True}}, {}, {}, {}}  *)

(* Poles *)
FunctionProperties`Singularities[1/(x + 2), {x}]
(*  {{}, {}, {{1 + x == 0, True}}, {}, {}}  *)

(* Essential singularities *)
FunctionProperties`Singularities[Exp[1/(x + 3)], {x}]
(*  {{}, {}, {}, {{3 + x == 0, True}}, {}}  *)

(* Altogether *)
FunctionProperties`Singularities[
 Log[x] + Sign[x + 1] + 1/(x + 2) + Exp[1/(x + 3)], {x}]
(*
{{{Im[x] == 0, Re[x] <= 0}},
 {{1 + x == 0, True}},
 {{2 + x == 0, True}},
 {{3 + x == 0, True}},
 {{x == 0, True}}}
*)
```

`` Visualization`ExpandExclusions[f, {x}, Automatic] `` does nearly the same thing without categorization, presumably in a way more appropriate to the `*Plot` and `*Plot3D` families of functions (e.g., it makes a *`TimeConstrained[]`* call to `` Join @@ FunctionProperties`Singularities[...] ``).  These are undocumented functions, and what I know about them comes from other posts on this site and testing examples as above.  `` FunctionProperties`Singularities `` has a third argument (search the site) that apparently affects what types of singularities are returned.  It can be a set of the following string keys:

```
f = Log[x] + Sign[x + 1] + 1/(x + 2) + Exp[1/(x + 3)];
FunctionProperties`Singularities[f, {x}, {"ALL"}]
FunctionProperties`Singularities[f, {x}, {"BRANCHCUTS"}]
FunctionProperties`Singularities[f, {x}, {"DEFCUTS"}]
FunctionProperties`Singularities[f, {x}, {"POLES"}]
FunctionProperties`Singularities[f, {x}, {"ESSENTIAL"}]
FunctionProperties`Singularities[f, {x}, {"BRANCHPOINTS"}]
FunctionProperties`Singularities[f, {x}, {"CUTS"}]
FunctionProperties`Singularities[f, {x}, {"POINTS"}]
FunctionProperties`Singularities[f, {x}, {"IGNORE"}]    (*?*)
FunctionProperties`Singularities[f, {x}, {"PWMINMAX"}]  (*?*)
```

They seem to return what is indicated by the string, but I don't know what is indicated by the last two.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand what is FunctionProperties`Singularities means? It is not a internal Function right? Could you explain a bit about it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SaberTifa  It's an undocumented internal function.  It was the hidden workhorse for finding singularities up until `FunctionSingularities` was introduced in V12.2  Discontinuity processing was introduced in Mathematica a long time ago and has evolved every version or two ever since.  V12.2 is the first time it has been made available at the user ``System` `` level and might be using a new algorithm, since it does not seem to call ``FunctionProperties`Singularities``. I'm not sure why they chose to have it return a `Reduce`-like expression instead of an `Exclusions`-like one.

Comment: @SaberTifa OTOH, my main purpose was to explain the syntax for `Exclusions`, to which the return values of the older discontinuity processing functions conform.

Answer (score 2):

For your example, you can convert the Singularities, since they are all of the form `x==something || x==something` etc... to `{}`

```
ClearAll[F, x, any];
F = 1/x + 1/(x + 1);
sing = FunctionSingularities[F, x]
sing = (List @@ sing) /. x == any_ :> any;
NIntegrate[F, {x, -3, 2}, Method -> "PrincipalValue", Exclusions -> sing]

(*-4.44089*10^-16*)
```

But this will not always work if the Singularities do not have this form, depending on the function.  For example, from help

```
 FunctionSingularities[Log[x], x, Complexes]
```

gives

```
 x == 0 || (Im[x] == 0 && Re[x] <= 0)
```

And so the above parsing will not work on this case.

Comment: Thank you. It works, May I ask one more question? In the fourth line, you use List @@ sing, but when I change it to List[sing], it doesn't work. Do you know what is the difference between List@@ and List[]? Thanks.

Comment: @SaberTifa  `List@@sing` changes the head to `List`. so that `||` becomes `,`.   But `List[sing]` just puts a list around, without changing `||`.  btw, I suggest you consider accepting Michael E2 answer below instead of mine, as it is more general and works for different type of singularities, while mine works only for those in the form   `||` . I did not know about the undocumented method used there.